# Border issue on Linear Layout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

[image]

> Above is the screen shot of my apps Dashboard screen. Each of the Dash board item is a Linear Layout which i have made clickable and have applied the background.xml on OnClick event to show a different background color on click.
>   The problem i am having is the extra grey line at the top of Purcahse History.

And i am stuck to it since long .

THis is my **background.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid android:color="@drawable/bgColorButtonClick" />
 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@drawable/llBorderColor" />
 <padding android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="15dp" />
 </shape>
```

Any help is highly appreciated .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like there is a small gap between `Purchase History` and the view above it. It would not be unlikely if you are seeing the stroke at the bottom of that view just above the stroke for the `Purchase History`.

Comment: can u see a gap between purchase history and item below ?
if not the item above purchse history is placed exactly the way item below it is placed . this appears only when item is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the stroke in your background.xml file.

Why not just set a different background color programmatically? E.g.

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Comment: setting only the background color removes the border :)

Comment: So you have another xml for the original background / border?